# What gives stellar value?

Tags: xlm, bridge-currency

As a bridge currency, why does it need to have value or increase in value from a practical standpoint? Is it all just speculation?

Answer (score 3):

It has no intrinsic value, i.e. it is not backed by other arbitrary good of value (e.g. Gold).

As a bridge currency, it needs to have a certain price in order to calculate exact exchange rate between XLM and the other 2 currencies / tokens being bridged.

Also, it is limited in value, and does have utility. Which makes the price vary due to fluctuations in supply & demand. So, if the demand goes up (&/or more buyers than sellers), the prices usually go up due to competition. And vice versa, if demand goes down *or* there are more sellers than buyers, then prices usually go down.